# How to set text in Y-axis, instead of numbers, in a RadChart component from Telerik with Bar-type

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radchart

I have made an bar RadChart with "SeriesOrientation="Horizontal"".

I have the text showing at the end for each bars, but instead I would like that text to be listet in the y-axis, instead of the 1,2,3.. numbers.

It seems like I'm not allow to set any text in the y-axis, is there a property I can set?

Here is my code snippes:
=== .ascx ===

```
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" />

        <asp:UpdatePanel  ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <telerik:RadChart ID="RadChart1" runat="server"
                    Skin="WebBlue" AutoLayout="true" Height="350px" Width="680px" SeriesOrientation="Horizontal">
                    <Series>
                        <telerik:ChartSeries DataYColumn="UnitPrice" Name="Product Unit Price">
                        </telerik:ChartSeries>
                    </Series>
                    <PlotArea>
                        <YAxis>
                            <Appearance>
                                <TextAppearance TextProperties-Font="Verdana, 8.25pt, style=Bold" />
                            </Appearance>
                        </YAxis>
                        <XAxis DataLabelsColumn="TenMostExpensiveProducts">
                        </XAxis>
                    </PlotArea>
                    <ChartTitle>
                        <TextBlock Text="Ten Most Expensive Products" />
                    </ChartTitle>
                </telerik:RadChart>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>

=========================

=== .ascx ===
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RadChart1.AutoLayout = false;
            RadChart1.Legend.Visible = false;

            // Create a ChartSeries and assign its name and chart type
            ChartSeries chartSeries = new ChartSeries();
            chartSeries.Name = "Name";
            chartSeries.Type = ChartSeriesType.Bar;

            // add new items to the series,
            // passing a value and a label string
            chartSeries.AddItem(98, "Product1");
            chartSeries.AddItem(95, "Product2");
            chartSeries.AddItem(100, "Product3");
            chartSeries.AddItem(75, "Product4");
            chartSeries.AddItem(1, "Product5");

            // add the series to the RadChart Series collection
            RadChart1.Series.Add(chartSeries);
            // add the RadChart to the page.
            //                this.Page.Controls.Add(RadChart1);

            //            RadChart1.Series[0].Appearance.LegendDisplayMode = ChartSeriesLegendDisplayMode.Nothing;
            //            RadChart1.Series[0].DataYColumn = "Uptime";
            RadChart1.PlotArea.XAxis.DataLabelsColumn = "Name";
            RadChart1.PlotArea.XAxis.Appearance.TextAppearance.TextProperties.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8);
            RadChart1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            RadChart1.Height = 350;
            RadChart1.Width = 570;
            RadChart1.DataBind();
        }
```

============
I want to have the text: "Product1", "Product2", etc in the y-axis.

can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the chart -- set the DataSource property and call DataBind(). You will not need to call chartSeries.AddItem(). DataBind() will add the items for you. The datasource can be a DataTable with two columns -- "UnitPrice" and "TenMostExpensiveProducts". See, these are the names you set to DataYColumn in the series and DataLabelsColumn in XAxis.